# Проблема отображения кодировки

Tags: php, кодировка, denwer

Установлен локальный веб сервер денвер последней версии, есть php файл в котором указана кодировка utf-8 формат этого этого файла utf-8 без BOM, а на выводе текст отображается в cp1251 кодировке. Что делать?

[image: result]

Comment: у него наверное в настройках апача по дефолту прописано 1251 и она перебивает кодировку указанную в файле....надо посмотреть defaultcharset поменять. вдруг поможет.........а еще я советую убить денвер и перейти хотя бы на опенсервер....денвер давно помер уж и новье не поддерживает.....mysql давно 5.7. есть,... php 7 и apache 2.4.....а в денвере этого нет......

Comment: Этим старьем еще кто-то пользуется? Я про Денвер.

Comment: Денвер уже несколько лет не обновляется и в комплекте идёт настолько древняя версия PHP, что лучше пересядьте на что-то более современное типа OpenServer. Rest in peace, Denwer, шикарная ты была среда разработки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заключается проблема в том, что в конфигурационном файле Денверовского Apache-сервера в качестве дефолтной кодировки красуется “Windows-1251″, по этой причине в браузеры насильно передается инструкция использования именно этой кодировки для чтения открываемых сайтов. Очень часто эта инструкция воспринимается как основополагающая, и браузер не обращает внимания на то, что Вы передаете  с помощью мета-тега.

httpd.conf отвечает за глобальные инструкции для сервера, т.е. внесенные в него изменения повлияют на все сайты, которые у нас будут храниться на сервере. Нужно отредактировать его: ищем “AddDefaultCharset windows-1251″ и меняем её на “AddDefaultCharset utf-8″.

Перезапустите сервер и все должно стать нормально :)

Comment: все верно, спасибо за помощь, через пару минут получите лучший ответ